# Como enviar e-mail com PHP?

Tags: php, html, email

Eu tenho um site em construção que as pessoas tem a possibilidade de inserir um email, eu gostaria que assim que elas inserissem o seu email e clicassem no botão "inscrever", fosse mandado um email de resposta automática para elas, como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: o simples uso da função mail() não serve?

Comment: Se puder me demonstrar como faz com algum exemplo, eu agradeço.

Comment: Eu uso a class phpmail ela é muito boa por sinal, veja um tutorial nesse link http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/enviar-e-mails-localhost-com-php-e-phpmailer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dê uma lida sobre a função [mail](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) do PHP.
Se você estiver utilizando uma hospedagem padrão ela deve estar pré configurada.

Com a função `mail` funcionando, basta você criar um formulário HTML para realizar essa ação.

Um exemplo básico de utilização

index.html

```
<form method="post" name="meu-form" action="send-mail.php">     
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome">     
Email:    <input type="text" name="email">     
Mensagem:  <textarea name="mensagem"></textarea>     
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

send-mail.php

```
<?php
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $mensagem= $_POST['mensagem'];
  $to = "contato@exemplo.com.br";
  $assunto = "Mensagem de ".$email.com
  mail($to,$assunto,$mensagem);
?>
```

Comment: Queria um exemplo, só pra eu entender melhor porque li sobre essa função e não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Está certo?
index.html

 <form action="save.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">    
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Insira seu email" id="email"/>
    <button  id="inscricao" type="submit" value="inscricao">Inscrever 
    </button>
  </form>
save.php

<?php 
 
$email = $_POST['email'];
  

$headers = 'De: meuemail@exemplo.com' . "\r\n"
     'Para: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n"
$assunto = 'assunto';
$mensagem = 'mensagem de exemplo.';
mail($email, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);
?>

Comment: Conheci esse site hoje, desculpa a formatação aí porque não sei mexer direito ainda. Mas se puder ver se estou correto ou não, agradeço.

Comment: Acredito que o header utilizando "De" e "Para" não funciona. Mas ele não é necessário caso já tenha sido pré configurado. No mais, está tudo certo aparentemente.

Comment: Esse "De" e "Para", como deixar pré-configurado? É do mesmo modo que o assunto e a mensagem?

Comment: No servidor web que você utiliza.

Comment: @João o header não deve ser traduzido. Isso carrega informações usadas pelo servidor de emails. Ficando: $header = "From: endereco-do-visitante@dominio.com\n";

Comment: @gtonioli, quando utilizo o mail aqui, o e-mail vai para o lixo eletrônico, sabe porque?

Answer (score -1):

Outra forma de fazer o envio dos dados é a seguinte:

```
<?php
   //Variáveis que recebem os dados digitados no formulário pelo id atribuído nos input
   $nome = $POST[nome]; 
   $email = $POST[email];
   $assunto = $POST[assunto];
   $mensagem = $POST[mensagem];

mail (
    "contato@seunome.com", //Endereço que vai receber a mensagem
    "Nome: $nome
     Email: $email
     Assunto: $assunto
     Mensagem: $mensagem", "FROM:$nome<$email>");
?>
```

Eu não sou programador, mas esse jeito não é tão seguro eu acho porque em outros tem a verificação dos dados para prevenir do usuário enviar dados maliciosos pelo formulário. Mas ele funciona normal.