# Enviar mail com dados de um form

Tags: html, email

Eu tenho um [form](http://gyazo.com/f61703732a2de2f9500db516d1e9a402) num ficheiro **html** e precisava que ao clicar no **submit** os dados fossem enviados para um mail. Já experimentei colocar no **form**, **action="mailto:...."**, que foi a única solução que encontrei, mas quando clicava no **submit** limitava-se a ir para o outlook.
Alguém sabe como fazer para que ao submeter os dados fossem enviado para um mail?

```html
<form action="php/mail.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome"  required> 
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"  required>
  <textarea id="message" name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"required></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Apagar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Pode ser com php?

Comment: @gustavox pode ser com o que for, eu preciso que isto funcione só isso. E ainda por cima eu sou relativamente novo nisto.

Comment: Posta o código HTML do form... e vc sabe que com PHP, vai precisar rodar num servidor que suporte PHP. O HTML não envia e-mail do jeito que vc está querendo, ele abre o navegador preenchendo as informações do form que corresponderem aos campos, mas o envio tem que ser pelo próprio usuário. O PHP vai empacotar tudo e enviar direto. Posta aí o código do HTML pra eu ver se consigo te ajudar...

Comment: coloca os campos do form q vc tem

Comment: Eu fiz uma resposta, mas vi agora que já existe uma pergunta igual com resposta aceita: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/como-enviar-e-mail-com-php?rq=1

Comment: @BrunoGibellino conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @gustavox desculpe não vi essa sua resposta mas vou já trabalhar nela. E desde já obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Então amigo, a maneira mais fácil, é utilizar um linguagem dinâmica exemplo php, asp, .net, mais alguns fatores também são bem cruciais o host onde seu site está hospedado porque isso influencia muito porque cada host tem sua configuração para envio de email. mais no google vc encontra vários tutoriais sobre isso: olha esse exemplo http://www.devmedia.com.br/enviar-formulario-por-e-mail-php/21757 qualquer dúvida posta sua dúvida. abraço.

Answer (score 0):

**Bruno**, o ideal é você utilizar o `PHPMailer` (em `PHP`). É famoso, bastante discutido aqui no `Stackoverflow` e super simples de implementar.

Basta você criar um arquivo (ex.: `phpmailer_enviar.php`) e importar a classe usando `require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");` o conteúdo recebido do form no corpo da mensagem em `$mail->Body`. Lembre-se que este arquivo deve o `action='phpmailer_enviar'`.

```
<?php
// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// (...)
```

**Veja um tutorial completo em:** http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/

Answer (score 0):

O HTML não possui função nativa para envio automático de e-mail, porque é `client side`. O que `mailto` faz, no máximo, é apenas abrir o cliente de e-mail com as informações do `form`.

Como disse no comentário, pra fazer isso você pode utilizar a função mail do PHP (que é `server side`), da seguinte forma:

Primeiro você **cria as variáveis** pra armazenar os valores vindos do `form`, usando a superglobal `$_POST`.

Por exemplo, se o campo `input` estiver assim:

```
<input type="text" name="nome">
<input type="text" name="endereco">
<input type="email" name="email">
```

As variáveis no PHP vão ficar assim:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];

?>
```

Depois, você cria as variáveis que a função `mail` do PHP vai utilizar pra enviar o e-mail: `$to`, `$subject`, `$msg`:

```
$to = "meuemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "O assunto";
$msg = "Nome: $nome \n Endereço: $endereco."; // aqui você pode incluir os campos que quiser
```

Daí chama a função `mail`:

```
mail($to, $subject, $msg);
```

Então juntando tudo vamos criar o arquivo **`enviaremail.php`** (edit: editei com base no seu HTML, testa e se der problema me avisa):

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Página de Enviar e-mail </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome']; // o $_POST usa o name pra pegar os dados
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

$to = "meuemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "O assunto";
$msg = "Nome: $nome\n" . // O \n pula uma linha e o . conecta os pedaços
"Mensagem: $mensagem\n" .
"Enviado por: $email"; 
// aqui você pode incluir os campos que quiser
mail($to, $subject, $msg);

echo "Obrigado por enviar seu email"; // esta será a mensagem na página de saída, depois do e-mail ser enviado, mas vc pode personalizar...

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Daí na página HTML vc chama o arquivo criado:

```
<form method="post" action="enviaremail.php">
```

Isso deve gerar uma saída assim em meuemail@gmail.com:

> Nome: [O nome digitado no form]; 
>   Endereço: [O endereço digitado no form];
>   Enviado por: [e-mail digitado no form];

Nota: Se por acaso estiver querendo enviar à partir de localhost já é um pouco mais complicado, mas existe a resposta aqui no SOpt: [Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/como-enviar-e-mail-do-localhost-usando-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mail-do-php)