# Erro ao enviar formulário para e-mail por PHP

Tags: php, html, email

Não sei o modo certo de se enviar dados de um formulário para um e-mail, utilizando o `PHP`.

Então, essa é a situação:

Página `contato.php`:

```
<form id="form-contato" action="enviar.php" method="post">
<h2>Fale com nossa Equipe!</h2>
<label for="Nome">Nome:</label><input type="text" name="Nome" id="Nome" maxlength="40"><br><br>
<label for="E-mail">E-mail:</label><input type="email" name="E-mail" id="E-mail" maxlength="60"><br><br>
<label for="Assunto">Assunto:</label>
<select name="Assunto" id="Assunto">
   <option selected disabled style="font-style:italic;">Selecione... </option>
   <option value="Interesse em ser Assinante">Interesse em ser Assinante</option>
   <option value="Reclamação">Reclamação</option>
   <option value="Perguntas">Perguntas</option>
</select><br>
<p>Mensagem:</p>
<div id="textarea">
<textarea id="Mensagem" cols="50" rows="7" name="Mensagem"></textarea>
                           </div>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Depois, a página `enviar.php`:

```
<?php
     $nome = $_POST['Nome'];
     $email = $_POST['E-mail'];
     $assunto = $_POST['Assunto'];
     $mensagem = $_POST['Mensagem'];
     $data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
     $hora_envio = date('H:i:s');

    //enviar

    // emails para quem será enviado o formulário
    $emailenviar = "meuemail@gmail.com";
    $destino = $emailenviar;

    // É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$nome.' <'.$email.'>';
    //$headers .= "Bcc: $EmailPadrao\r\n";
    $arquivo = "";
    $enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
    if($enviaremail){
        $mgm = "E-MAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO! <br> 
                O link será enviado para o e-mail 
                fornecido no formulário";
        echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;URL=contato.php'>";
    } else {
        $mgm = "ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
        echo "";
    }
?>
```

Então, quando eu envio o formulário, nada acontece. Só vai para uma página `enviar.php` e não dá ***ERRO AO ENVIAR O EMAIL*** e também não dá ***E-MAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO***. Simplesmente, nada acontece, só uma página em branco.

Eu gostaria de saber quais são os erros desse código e também outra dúvida, é que só pelo fato de eu dar upload até o servidor do meu site, já está funcionando o serviço de e-mail?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar e-mail com PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/como-enviar-e-mail-com-php)

Comment: No caso de erro voce nao esta apresentando nada. Tente substituir o `echo "";` por `echo $mgm;`.

Comment: É, agora está dando o erro mesmo. Mas como fazer pra resolver?

Comment: Nesse caso acredito que o link que o @GabrielRanéaBarbosa comentou deva te ajudar. Mas aproveitando que voce perguntou: _só pelo fato de eu dar upload até o servidor do meu site, já está funcionando o serviço de e-mail?_, Seu problema pode estar ai, verifique se a funcao `mail` do PHP esta corretamente configurada no seu servidor.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisei sobre a função `mail` e consegui agora. Obrigado!

Comment: Boa @NicolasS. Caso nenhuma das respostas dada tenha suprido sua necessiade, sugiro que responda sua propria pergunta descrevendo como resolveu e marque sua resposta como correta. Assim quem tiver o mesmo problema que voce teve pode achar sua resposta util.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu `echo "";` está vazio, veja:

```
if($enviaremail){
    $mgm = "E-MAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO! <br> 
            O link será enviado para o e-mail 
            fornecido no formulário";
    echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;URL=contato.php'>";
} else {
    $mgm = "ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
    echo "";
}
```

Mude pra isto:

```
if($enviaremail){
    $mgm = "E-MAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO! <br> 
            O link será enviado para o e-mail 
            fornecido no formulário";
    echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;URL=contato.php'>";
} else {
    $mgm = "ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
}

echo $mgm;
```