# Função mail() do php não funciona!

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email, sendmail

Tenho um sistema dentro do xampp que estou desenvolvendo, tentei usar a função mail do php pra enviar um email de recuperação de senha, mas não funciona. Alguem pode me ajudar ai faz dias que to com esse problema.

Código:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../classes/conexao.php');

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $_SESSION['campos'] = true;
    header('Location: ../view/recupera_senha.php');
    exit();
} else {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['email']));

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['invalido'] = true;
        header('Location: ../view/recupera_senha.php');
        exit();
    } else {

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS reg FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($row['reg'] == 1) {

            $novasenha = substr(md5(time()), 0, 6);
            $senhacriptografada = md5(md5($novasenha));

            try {      
                if(mail($email, "Title", "Mensagem", "Cabeçalho")) {
                    $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET senha = '$senhacriptografada' WHERE email = '$email'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);  

                    $_SESSION['enviado'] = true;
                    header('Location: ../view/recupera_senha.php');
                    exit();
                }             

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Exceção capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['inexistente'] = true;
            header('Location: ../view/recupera_senha.php');
            exit();
        }
    }          
}
```

?>

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar e-mail com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/como-enviar-e-mail-com-php)

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui resolver, o problema era que meu gmail que estava no sendmail do php não tava permitido a enviar email externo. Então tive que configurar meu gmail pra poder enviar. Não tinha nenhum problema no código.

Comment: `mail($email, "Title", "Mensagem", "Cabeçalho")`, esse `$Cabeçalho` não fez sentido algum no código.